# Can I pass a std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>> as a vector of raw pointer without extra allocations?

Tags: c++, vector, unique-ptr, raw-pointer

Suppose I have the following function:

```cpp
void sum(const std::vector<int*>& input) {
  return ... ; // the sum
}
```

I store a vector of int pointers somewhere

```cpp
...
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> my_ints;
```

Is there a way to pass `my_ints` to `sum()` without any extra allocations such as an intermediate vector of the unique_ptrs converted to a vector of raw pointers?

Obviously, I could refacor `sum()` to take a vector of unique ptrs instead. Or overload it. But I'm hoping to find a way where I don't have to, and let the user decide whether or not to use a vector of unique_ptrs or raw pointers.

Comment: Unrelated: There isn't much use for pointers to `int` unless you have a dynamic array of `int`, and in that case, `vector<vector<int>>` is almost always going to be a better choice.

Comment: I was thinking recently "Why there is no non-templated (except value type) iterators and ranges for non-contiguous containers (for contiguous you can use `std::span`). I think in your case that would be ideal solution. But since there is no implementation, that I aware of, you can try to implement one yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Not like you want, but you should think about `sum()` differently. It looks like an algorithm that operates on a range, so you should make it more like this:

```
template <typename It>
ValueType sum(It begin, It end) {
    // ... iterate and calculate sum
    return sum;
}
```

Then suddenly, you can start to use ranges to do cool things!

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> my_ints;
auto range = my_ints | ranges::views::transform
(
    [](auto smart_ptr) {
        return smart_ptr.get();
    }
);
```

This is a range that will transform as you use it! Then you could enter it into your `sum()` like this:

```
auto my_sum = sum(std::begin(range), std::end(range));
```

Also look up [`std::accumulate()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate), which does what you want here, I would say.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is absolutely no way to pass those pointer values to that `sum` method without changing the method.